# Prove that $\lfloor {(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})}^{4n-2}\rfloor-1$ is a square number where $n$ is a natural number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers, natural-numbers, golden-ratio

I found this problem in a junior high school math competition.

> Prove that $\lfloor {(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})}^{4n-2}\rfloor-1$ is a
> square number where $n$ is a natural number.

Here's what I think

Suppose $x$ is ${(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})}^2$

Then we get

$\lfloor {(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2})}^{4n-2}\rfloor-1$

$=(x^{2n-1}+\frac{1}{x^{2n-1}}-1)-1$

$=(x^{2n-1}-1)(1-\frac{1}{x^{2n-1}})$

$=(x-1)(1-\frac{1}{x})(x^{2n-2}+x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-4}+\ldots+1)(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{2n-2}})$

$=(x^{2n-2}+x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-4}+\ldots+1)(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{2n-2}})$

$=(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}})(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}})$

$=(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}})^2$

Now I hope to prove that $(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}})\in\mathbb{N}$

But I don't know how to continue, but I think there is something with the golden ratio, can someone help me, or provide a better solution for the original problem? Thanks a lot!

NEW: I found the same question on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1605938p10014762), I see that the original formula is equal to $((\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2})^{2n-1}-(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2})^{2n-1})^2$, but it just said that is actually the general form for the recurrence relation $a_n=3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$, which can be shown by the characteristic polynomials, but I still don't know why...

Comment: Which junior high school math competition did you find it in?

Comment: Notice that since $4n - 2$ will always be even ($2, 6, 10, ...$), you can rewrite $(\frac{1 + \sqrt5}{2})^{4n-2}$ as $(\frac{3 + \sqrt5}{2})^{2n - 1}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: I just finished a competition in my region Macau, China. And this is the last question of the competition. The paper is not shared yet but it is legal to post the question online.

Comment: Hint: What can we say about $x^k + x^{-k}$? If this is an integer, then we are done using what you have. $\quad$ In fact, your solution hints that it has to be an integer (by taking the difference of 2 of these supposed integers), so this is a natural next step to complete your solution.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is how to prove $x^k+x^{-k}$ is an integer

Comment: You already asked this yesterday. Please don't repost this question. It has been solved many times, e.g., in [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1725451p11172109).

Comment: Hi, if $x^0+x^0$ and $x^1+x^{-1}$ are integers, then $x^{k+1}+x^{-(k+1)}=(x^k+x^{-k})(x^1+x^{-1})-(x^{k-1}+x^{-(k-1)})$ is an integer by strong induction.

Comment: Hint: $(x^{2n-1}-1)(1-x^{1-2n})=(x^{n-1/2}-x^{1/2-n})^2$, so you need only prove$$x^{n-1/2}-x^{1/2-n}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n-1}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n-1}$$is an integer. (We usually write $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\,\overline{\varphi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.) [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not to be confused with [this exceedingly similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620233/proving-left-lfloor-frac1-sqrt524n2-right-rfloor-1-is-a-perfect?rq=1).*

---

I'll reproduce the solution found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1605938p10014762) (with a few added details).

Because $\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} < 1$, we also know that $\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{4n - 2} < 1$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{4n - 2}\right\rfloor -1 &= \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{4n - 2} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{4n - 2} - 2\\
&= \left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Thus, we only need to show that
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1} \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Using the Newton binomial formula we have
\begin{align}
    \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1} &= A_n \sqrt{5} +B_n\\
    \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1} &= A_n \sqrt{5} - 
    B_n
\end{align}
so
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{2 n-1}=2 B_n$$
where $A_n, B_n$ there are positive integers

Every term in this recurrence is an integer so
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} + 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\right)^{2n - 1} \in \mathbb{N}$$
and we are done.

Comment: If someone is curious, we can denote by $x_{1,2}$ the roots of $x^2-x-1$, i.e. they are $(1\pm\sqrt 5)/2$, then $x_i^n = F_n x_i + F_{n-1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number, so $x_1^n+x_2^n = F_n(x_1+x_2) + 2F_{n-1} = F_n+2F_{n-1}$ and the square number is $(F_{2n-1}+2F_{2n-2})^2.$

Comment: Yep, that was the method that it seems most were talking about. I chose to use the Newton binomial formula because I thought OP might understand it better.