# Proving $\left\lfloor(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{4n+2}\right\rfloor-1$ is a perfect square for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers, golden-ratio

Let $$S_n = \left \lfloor\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}\right\rfloor-1$$ ($n=0, 1, 2, \ldots$).
Prove that $S_n$ is a perfect square.

In Art of Problem Solving website, there is a hint
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lfloor\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}\right\rfloor-1 & =\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}-2\\
&=\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n+1}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

I don't know how to get the first equal sign, is it mean
$$
\left\lfloor\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}\right\rfloor = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}-\left\{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}\right\} $$

But how to prove the decimal part of $\phi^{4n+2}$
$$ \left\{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2} \right\} =1-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4n+2}$$

Comment: Sorry, typo... the link: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2551610p21815112

Comment: I removed the **[perfect-numbers]** tag and added the **[square-numbers]** tag.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi:=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and $\bar\varphi:=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2.$ The hint you wonder about,
$$\left\lfloor\varphi^{2m}\right\rfloor=\varphi^{2m}+\bar\varphi^{2m}-1,$$
is due to the fact that $\varphi^k+\bar\varphi^k$ is an integer (the $k$-th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)) and
$$\varphi^{2m}+\bar\varphi^{2m}-1\le\varphi^{2m}<\varphi^{2m}+\bar\varphi^{2m},$$
i.e.
$$0<\bar\varphi^{2m}\le1.$$

Answer (score 0):

By considering the binomial expansions of $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}$ and $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}$ it can be all non-integer terms cancel out when the two are added together, giving an integer result. Therefore we can say that $$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\in\mathbb{Z}$$
However, since $\left|\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right|<1$, $\left|\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right|<1$. Since the exponent of $\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$ is even, $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}>0$. Therefore, $$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}=\left\lceil\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right\rceil$$
If $m\notin\mathbb{Z}, \lceil m\rceil=\lfloor m\rfloor+1$.
$$\therefore\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}-1=\left\lceil\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right\rceil-1=\left\lfloor\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right\rfloor,$$
as required.

Comment: Note that if $\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ and $\bar\phi = (1-\sqrt{5})/2$ and $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number, then $F_n = (\phi^n - \bar\phi^n)/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I don't think it is useful here.

Comment: I think it's an elegant way to see that $\phi^{2n} + \bar\phi^{2n}$ is an integer.

Comment: Wouldn’t this connect your answer to OP?$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}=2\left\lceil\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right\rceil$$

Comment: @MeesdeVries ok, thank you, I got it (alternatively and more "directly": Lucas number, like in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let $$X_n=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{4n-2}=(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}=I+f, I \in I^+, 0 < f <1,0 <f'=(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}<1$$

$$X_n+f'=I+f+f'
=(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}+(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}$$
$$= (7+3\sqrt{5})^{n}\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}+(7-3\sqrt{5})^{n}\frac{2}{3-\sqrt{5}}=3A_n-5B_n=K$$
Where $(7+3\sqrt{5})^n=A_n+B_n\sqrt{5}, A_n. B_n \in I^+$

$K$ is integer,so is $I+f+f'$. This implies that $f+f'$ is also an integer as $0<f+f'<2$ and it equals 1. Hence $I=K-1.$

Check that $$K=\left((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}\right)^2+2. $$
$$\implies I-1=\left((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}\right)^{2}.$$
Check that $$(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}+(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2n-1}=(3+\sqrt{5})^n\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}+(3-\sqrt{5})^n\frac{2}{1-\sqrt{5}}$$
$$=5D_n-C_n,~ \text{where} ~(3+\sqrt{5})^n=C_n+D_n\sqrt{5}, C_n, D_n \in I^{+}.$$
Finally we have $I-1=(5D_n-C_n)^2, C_n, D_n \in I^+$